# requirejs does not inject anything at all, although the scripts are downloaded

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Whatever object I inject in the shell.js I can never access it.

It is downloaded from the server, I get no errors there or in the console output.

When I type the 'mainViewModel' in console I get this:

```
ReferenceError: mainViewModel is not defined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "mainViewModel is not defined"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

**app**.js:

```
require(['shell'], function(Shell) {
        var shell = new Shell();
});
```

**shell**.js:

```
define(['viewmodel/mainViewModel'], function (mainViewModel) {
    return function () {
        // When I am here the mainViewModel does not exist/undefined
    };
});
```

**MainViewModel**.js:

```
define([], function() {
    return function() {

    };
})
```

Comment: file name in define section is case sensitive. Try to change define(['viewmodel/mainViewModel']) to define(['viewmodel/MainViewModel'])

Comment: that did not help. I have never cared for case sensitive and it always worked. Above all if that would be the case I would get a require js script load error which I do not have!

Comment: Try this require(['shell', 'viewmodel/mainViewModel'])
mainViewModel module must be included before usage.

Comment: The mainViewModel is required where it is used and that is the shell.js, so why should I require it in the app.js ??? That makes no sense and defeats the purpose of requirejs/modularity...

Comment: You are right, but when I've repeated your code, it works fine  :)

Comment: repeated my code? Just to be clear, you mean put the mainViewModel injection  beside the shell injection?

Comment: No, just your code as is

Comment: Try caching preventing: <script>require.config({urlArgs: 'q=' + (new Date().getTime())})</script>

Comment: while I was starting commenting here I solved the mainViewModel problem, but now I have another nearly same problem... The mainViewModel gets jquery and a .js file (another viewmodel) injected. Jquery is injected but the other viewmodel is always undefined just like the first problem, I get crazy... :S

Comment: I wish you Good Luck in your Fight :)

Answer (score 0):

Require js sometimes return nulls when there are script errors in the file it is pulling down, I'm sure I've seen this happen to me before and it always turned out to be a missing } or ; or something similar (I notice a missing ; at the end of MainViewModel but its right at the end so I wouldn't suspect it heavily, i dunno if these files have any extra code in them? or are they really blank).

There is also the issue that Stanislav mentioned about the cache - since if its cached and you fix it then it will just resend the cached broken file (constantly clearing cache when developing can be a good habit lol). Actually the urlArgs should probably be used with version numbers in production as well, users clearing cache is not going to happen consistently after upgrades...

returning the function is all fine and well but if you create a variable, assign the function to it and then return the variable it makes it easier to debug the actual file thats being pulled down, if you can get the breakpoint into it and remembered after a refresh.
Then you can see the object that is being returned, if the code even hits that file or if there is an error with the object generation (which I suspect)

Bit of an old one... I'm sure you've either sorted your issues or abandoned require js in frustration by now :)